# Siebel Open UI - Add attachment via javascript

Tags: javascript, attachment, siebel

I am working in “Siebel eservice” to "Open UI" conversion project. I am trying to do the following, any idea would help.

Expectation:

1. User Clicks on New SR
2. Fills in SR Product, SR Details etc..
3. In the same flow, I want users to add “Attachment”, once added this attachment should be posted to attachment BC.
4. Today we have smartscript to do in “eService”
5. In open UI we are NOT using smartscript

Please suggest some alternate options with Javascript / Jquery.

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the Smart Script solution is no longer available?

Comment: Hi - It is that we made a decision to go with Open UI framework, as it more flexible than smartscript.

Comment: Smart Script is used to support a specific business task and ensure that all the steps are performed in the right order. Smart Script is a sound way of doing this in a maintainable way. Writing large amounts of custom browser script code to replace out-of-the-box configuration doesn't sound like a good strategy to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.